# Disable prompt for failed connections in vba

Tags: excel, vba, warnings, prompt

I'm trying to write a vba code that will basically crawl designated folders/subfolder, open the excel files (~6000) and replace a few strings.

The problem is these excel files have links to addins and while the macro is opening the files the prompt appears with a "failed to connect to" message. Meaning you have to click every time the macro opens the files so they can skip the prompts.

This happens only when the macro is opening the file, opening manually no prompts are displayed.

```
Sub FindReplaceInFolder()
Dim fso As Object
Dim folder As Object
Dim subfolder As Object
Dim file As Object
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFileSpec As String
Dim strFind1 As String
Dim strReplace1 As String
Dim strFind2 As String
Dim strReplace2 As String

' Set the folder path and file specification
strFolder = "C:\Users\path"
strFileSpec = "*.xls*"

' Set the find and replace strings
strFind1 = "oldtex"
strReplace1 = "newtex"
strFind2 = "oldtext2"
strReplace1 = "newtext2"


' Create a File System Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Get the folder object
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(strFolder)

'Loop each subfolders
For Each subfolder In folder.Subfolders

    ' Loop through all files in the folder
    For Each file In subfolder.Files
        
        ' Check if the file matches the file specification
        If file.Name Like strFileSpec Then
        
            ' Open the workbook
            Workbooks.Open file.Path
            
            'displays no prompts
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            
            ' Replace the text in all sheets of the workbook
            Call ReplaceInWorkbook(strFind1, strReplace1)
            Call ReplaceInWorkbook(strFind2, strReplace2)
            
            ' Save and close the workbook
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            
        End If
        
    Next file

Next subfolder

End Sub

Sub ReplaceInWorkbook(strFind As String, strReplace As String)
Dim ws As Worksheet

' Loop through all sheets in the workbook
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    
    ' Replace the text in all cells of the sheet
    ws.Cells.Replace What:=strFind, Replacement:=strReplace, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: how about disabling prompts BEFORE opening a Workbook. The prompt that is shown is most certainly shown onOpen, so disabling prompts after you've already opened the Workbook does nothing. - `DisplayAlerts` is a property on the `Application` object, so it is not WB specific, but is for the whole Excel Instance.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something but can't you just put `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` outside your for loops since the prompt comes when opening the file?

Comment: Yup, that did it. How could have I missed it...